# Linear independence and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

1. For what values of a is the set of vectors (1, 0, a), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0 1) linearly independent?
2. For what values of a is the set of the same vectors a basis of $R^3$?

For question 1 I row reduced to (1, 0, 0)(0, 1, 0)(1, 0, 1-a), so I got it's linearly independent for all values except a = 1. And I'm getting the same answer for the 2nd question.

Is there a difference between the 2? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If a list of vectors with dimension the size of the space is linearly independent, then it is necessarily a basis for the space. So, if you find that 
$$a≠1\implies (1,0,a),(0,1,0),(1,0,1)$$
linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then from the fact that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $3$, that list of vectors functions as a basis.

So to be clear- in this particular case these questions are identical.